# How can we validate tabular data in robot framework?

Tags: database, bdd, robotframework, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

In Cucumber, we can directly validate the database table content in tabular format by mentioning the values in below format:

  `| Type | Code | Amount |
  | A    | HIGH | 27.72  |
  | B    | LOW  | 9.28   |
  | C    | LOW  | 4.43   |`

Do we have something similar in Robot Framework. I need to run a query on the DB and the output looks like the above given table.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing built in to do exactly what you say. However, it's fairly straight-forward to write a keyword that takes a table of data and compares it to another table of data.

For example, you could write a keyword that takes the result of the query and then rows of information (though, the rows must all have exactly the same number of columns):

```
| | ${ResultOfQuery}= | <do the database query>
| | Database should contain  | ${ResultOfQuery}
| | ... | #Type    | Code    | Amount
| | ... | A        | HIGH    | 27.72
| | ... | B        | LOW     | 9.28
| | ... | C        | LOW     | 4.43
```

Then it's just a matter of iterating over all of the arguments three at a time, and checking if the data has that value. It would look something like this:

```
**** Keywords *** 
| Database should contain
| | [Arguments] | ${actual} | @{expected}
| | :FOR | ${type} | ${code} | ${amount} | IN | @{expected}
| | | <verify that the values are in ${actual}>
```

Even easier might be to write a python-based keyword, which makes it a bit easier to iterate over datasets.

Comment: This does not work. The tabular column is not identified as a scalar variable. Instead RF throws an error stating, "expected 1 to 5 arguments, got 0".

Comment: @DeeptiK: I don't know what you mean. Without seeing your actual data it's impossible to know what the problem is. Most likely, your data isn't what you think it is, and you are passing in an empty string rather than a list with data. In any case, this isn't a limitation of robot, it's simply a bug in your keyword or in your test.

Comment: @Deeptik this would happen case1; when you have not seperated the arguments by at least two spaces or a proper tab, if robot file are tab seperated case2: if the robot file are pipe seperated, then it would work in above example as provided by Bryan